# Inherited vs local MIME type

Tags: iis

I am trying to add a MIME type. 
After adding it, the browser does not recognize the type.
When I compare it to the demo that works, the only difference that I can see is that in the demo the Entry type is inherited and the one I produce Is Local.
Could anyone explain the difference (I was unable to find anything about it on google).
How do I produce inherited MIME type? (on the demo is was just created that way, but on the beta site it is create as Local!?!)
BTW, in both demo and beta site it is version 6.1.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify MIME types at different levels.

When looking at a web site and seeing that the `Entry Type` is `Inherited` it means the site inherits this MIME type from the server level configuration.

Select the server node and then the `MIME types` icon, here you see all local entry types. You can add a new MIME type here, it will then show up as `inherited` type in all your web sites.

A local MIME type at the site level should still work.